# Setting DateTime in Flask App

Tags: python, datetime, flask

I am working on a flask app and I was wondering if someone can help me figure out why I am getting an error as I am trying to set the DateTime when a new user is registering an account. I just want it to save the exact time that the user was registered. The following is the route that I created to add and commit the user to the database.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask import escape, session
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database import Users, Base

app.route('/registered', methods=['Get', 'POST'])
def Register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.form['password']
        verify = request.form['verify']
        if password == verify:
            newUser = Users(Username = request.form['username'],
                            Password = request.form['password'],
                            Email = request.form['email'],
                            DateTime = datetime.now())
            session.add(newUser)
            session.commit()
            return redirect('HomePage')
        else:
            flash('Passwords do not match')
            return render_template('Register.html')
```

And here is the database structure that I currently have setup:

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    Username = Column(String(22), unique = True, nullable = False)
    Password = Column(String(22), nullable = False)
    Email = Column(String(55), unique = True, nullable = False)
    Registered = Column(DateTime, nullable = False)
```

I am not sure if the html file would have anything with setting up the datetime property.

If anyone can help. it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are passing a keyword argument `DateTime` to the `Users` constructor but it's expecting `Registered`.

Comment: That fixed the problem that I had. Can you add your comment as an answer so that I can upvote it and check it to let people know that it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the request handler, you pass a keyword argument `DateTime` to the `Users` constructor:

```
app.route('/registered', methods=['Get', 'POST'])
def Register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.form['password']
        verify = request.form['verify']
        if password == verify:
            newUser = Users(Username = request.form['username'],
                            Password = request.form['password'],
                            Email = request.form['email'],
                            DateTime = datetime.now())
```

But the `Users` model does not have a `DateTime` column, the correct name is `Registered`:

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    Username = Column(String(22), unique = True, nullable = False)
    Password = Column(String(22), nullable = False)
    Email = Column(String(55), unique = True, nullable = False)
    Registered = Column(DateTime, nullable = False)
```